# What request format is needed to connect the WCF server

Tags: java, json, wcf

I am using this type of request:

```
[
    method = Register, 
    gender = male, 
    email = aaaa@ aaa.aa, 
    password = aaaaa, 
    password_confirm = aaaaaa
]
```

And I don't know is it JSON type or no?
What kind of request content type I need to define in my WCF server for solving this String?

Comment: java and wcf? are you sure about the tags?

Comment: i would regard this as bad code.use {} instead of [] and stringify your values and you will end up with valid JSON. as @J.Wells noted, this is invalid JSON